# Product view image slider

Tags: media, product-view, gallery

A lot of our products in Magento have only 1 image. Is it possible to remove the image slider below the main product image if only 1 image exist? If 2 images or more then it should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default `media.phtml is showing gallery image`.Here  `getGalleryImages() show all images of product`.By `Default gallery show when count of gallery image is greater than 0`.You need to change `this 0 to 1`.

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 1): ?>
```